# Dynamic fields?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content where admins can add a new page. For now, I have the following fields.

1. Section 1 Title
2. Section 1 Body
3. Section 2 Title
4. Section 2 Body

I like to make it so that admins can add x number of sections dynamically. Is this even possible in Drupal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module to do this pretty easily.

You can set up a field collection containing your 'Title' and 'Body' fields (and any other number of fields you choose to add in the future), set the cardinality to 'Unlimited', and your users can take advantage of the in-built 'Add another' feature that fields has.

I normally install the [Field Collection Table](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_table) module as well, it offers a more UX friendly widget if you've got more than a couple of fields in the collection. I'm not sure how well this would work if you need to use a textarea for the body though.

Comment: Clive // Wow, I didn't know there's such plugin. Looks really nice and exactly what I wanted. Thanks!!